# Statement from text file to code

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to convert conditional statements from a text file straight to code.
For example, if in a text file I had:

```
if(a.getId()==1){System.out.println("YES");}
```

Is it possible to directly call that into a program, such as this:

```
for(Node a : nodes){
 >>> The statement from file <<<
}
```

Hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Java is a compiled language. You cannot plug in an arbitrary piece of code, and let it execute in the full context of your method, commplete with references to loop variables. You can achieve the desired result with some serious limitations, but it is extremely complex.

Comment: I know of a way to do it indirectly, where you can spawn another process to run this code and do it in a new JVM - it would require creating a temporary file with the for loop and the statement from the file, compiling that temporary file, and running it using processes. Is this what you are looking for (rather indirect way that barely affects the main thread code)

Comment: this is like writing the compiler ,  parse the code , and convert

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Thank you for the simple, yet informative,  explanation. :)

Comment: @Bucco - Thanks for the suggestion, this is mainly for a assignment I have involving decision trees and extracting rules from it so I don't think it exactly in the scope of the assignment, but thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to use a script engine. Or you can use [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html)
 which is straight forward. Example below.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell gShell = new GroovyShell(binding);
Object result= shell.evaluate("int a = 10; a = a + 5; return a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  Java is compiled, not interpreted.  I've seen template engines that generate complete java classes and then compile them into runnable code but it gets pretty hairy pretty quick.